# Method to find x,y point on a spline that is an exact distance from another point

Tags: python

I have a 2-d Spline that is a list of (x,y) tuples. I need to determine a point on the spline where a line of length L falls if one end of the line is placed on an existing spline point.

```
spline=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(xn,yn).....]
Line=200
for i in spline:
    find (xn,yn) 200 units from here
```

So for each point in the spline, find a (Xn,Yn) (or interpolated value) that is a linear distance of 200 from the chosen point.

Comment: Are your tuples actually points on the curve of the spline, or are they the control points used to define the spline? How do you want to deal with multiple matches (it's entirely possible to have a spline that has multiple, or even infinite, points equidistant from a specific point - a spline can transcribe a circle, after all)?

Comment: The tuples are actual points. The real (Xn,Yn) may not actually be in the list of tuples, but possibly an interpolated value between points.

Comment: sorry, replied from mobile phone and didn't see the entire question until after comment post.....little background.....the "line" in this example is a mechanical link that travels along a spline of my own design. Generally, the link will travel in one direction (say right to left) with the selected point being on the end of the link at the rightmost position. I think that the solution for the other points would contain an X value that is always less than the selected point.

Answer (score 0):

Why not compute the distances and compare them to "Line" like this

```
   spline=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(xn,yn).....]
    Line=200
    for x1,y1 in spline:
       for x2,y2 in spline:
           dist=math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
           if dist==Line:
              print x1,y1,'is Line distant from',x2,y2
```